# loading applet in the web browser's page

Tags: java, browser, applet

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Color;
public class sampleapp extends Applet {
    public void init() {
        this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);        
    }
}
```

I am trying to load the above mentioned applet in mozilla browser.

```
<applet code="sampleapp.class" width="100" height="100"></applet>
```

After hosting that web page (index.HTML file where I embed the applet), I have been getting the status information in the web page as *Applet sampleapp started*, but I am not getting the applet's content in that hosted web page (in my example, I am not getting the applet's background as black, instead I am just getting a blank web page).

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to actually draw something by overriding the `paint(Graphics g)` method. There are some other applet lifecycle methods you may want to override too. Have a look at the [Sun tutorial on the Applet lifecycle](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/deployment/applet/lifeCycle.html) which includes a working example of a basic applet right near the top.